# Xindy error: "A" does not name a letter group

Tags: glossaries, xindy

I have a problem with calling the makeglossaries script.
Here is a MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
% !TeX spellcheck = ru_RU

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{exm}{123}{Пример} % russian acronym

Штука называется \gls{exm}. % some russian text

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

System: Windows 8, TeX Live 2013 (up to date), TeXstudio as IDE.
The first compile run is fine - I get .glo .glsdefs and .xdy files. When I run makeglossaries script after, I receive the following log with error:

```
 ERROR: "A" does not name a letter group in
 (DEFINE-LETTER-GROUP "glsnumbers" :PREFIXES
 ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9") :BEFORE "A")

 *** Unable to execute: '"xindy"  -L russian -C utf8 -I xindy -M "temp" -t "temp.glg" -o "temp.gls" "temp.glo"' ***

 Failed with error code 1.

 Status report:

 Opening logfile "temp.glg" (done)
 Reading indexstyle...
 Loading module "0tI0EhWrtr"...
 Loading module "lang/russian/utf8-lang.xdy"...
 Loading module "lang/russian/utf8.xdy"...
 Finished loading module "lang/russian/utf8.xdy".
 Finished loading module "lang/russian/utf8-lang.xdy".
 Loading module "temp.xdy"...
 Loading module "tex.xdy"...
 Finished loading module "tex.xdy".

 Error in line 426:


 ; additional letter groups

 (define-letter-group "glsnumbers"
    :prefixes ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9")
    :before "A")
 ERROR: "A" does not name a letter group in
 (DEFINE-LETTER-GROUP "glsnumbers" :PREFIXES
  ("0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9") :BEFORE "A")
 C:\Dev\TeXLive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: command failed with exit code 1:
 perl.exe c:/Dev/TeXLive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/xindy/xindy.pl -L russian -C utf8 -I xindy -M "temp" -t "temp.glg" -o "temp.gls" "temp.glo"
```

I can't understand, why is this happenning. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not using a Latin alphabet, you either need to specify the first letter of your alphabet using `\GlsSetXdyFirstLetterAfterDigits` (before `\makeglossaries`) for example:

```
\GlsSetXdyFirstLetterAfterDigits{А}
```

Or you need to use the `xindy={glsnumbers=false}` package option:

```
\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}]{glossaries}
```